# Unattended Install

Tags: server, system-installation

I would like to install ubuntu server uattendedly. There are already a few topics about this, but most i cannot use...
I want to use preseed, but i don't really get this tutorial:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Cobbler/Preseed#Creating_the_preseed

How do i get my preseed inside there ? How to make it work without a keyboard ?

Comment: I do not understand the question. Everything is explained quite clearly in the link you provided. Why would you have preseed files on your iso that you *don't* want?

Comment: @user535733 I don't know how to make Ubuntu choose the preseed automaticaly when placing a usb stick in the server. Are preseeds run automatically ?

Comment: You don't *choose* anything. If there is a valid preseed file, the installer will use it.

Comment: Oh damn ! hahaha, my bad, jesus !

Comment: @user535733 But can i delete all the already existing preseeds, and just put mine ?

Comment: Advice: Test installing into a VM. You DON'T want your first try to be on real hardware. That gets expensive.

Comment: If there are existing preseeds, read them. If they don't do what you want, delete them.

Comment: @user535733 Thank you very much !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79879/discussion-between-pastudent-and-user535733).